# Javascript disable the same event / disable event globally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two javascript, booth have the same click event, one for check input fields check, second for do action.

Is it possible to disable the click event of do_action.js from check.js click event? But, without any additional statements in do_action.js click event!

I just want the check.js and do_action.js will work independently of each other.

[image]

check.js:

```
$("button").click
(
    function()
    {
        //if wrong name or email, than globally disable this event now
        return false;
    }
);
```

do_action.js:

```
$("button").click
(
    function()
    {
        //do action
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm a little lost here - so when you click a button, two separate and independent events fire; one that checks the data and the other that does some action?

Comment: Yes, one check data and other does action.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to disable the click event of do_action.js from check.js click event?

Kind of, but not in the way you're trying to do.

Since when the button event in invoked, both of your events will be fired asynchronously in parallel with each other, therefore your `check` event won't actually affect your `do_action` event.

The approach you'd need for this is to instead of *disabling the event*, you would *attach the event* once your condition is met. However, this doesn't work really well because you'd have to invoke this event twice for it to work.

Instead, try to just fire your `do_action` method if your `check` event is valid and only use one event:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    // Have a function that checks for input validity
    if(check_valid_input()){
        // Valid input, so now you can call your do_action
        do_action();
    }else{
        // Invalid input
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem that I need avoid to adding conditions to the do_action.

Comment: @Sevi Perhaps my solution was not clear or I'm misunderstanding your situation - in my solution you don't do anything with `do_action`, you just call it when a certain condition is met

Comment: The situation is I have some plugin which have javascript with click event that does some action. I don't want touch this plugin because the updates... So I want to do my additional changes to this plugin independently.